# creating modbus request packet in Qt creator

Tags: c++, c++11

hello all I'm using the qt creator platform to use the Modbus container classes. I'm parsing a CSV file that will contain my request packet such as the slave id, function code, start address,address count, and crc. I've tried to use the qt Modbus class but I can seem to construct a correct packet pass in the Modbus function and send to a serial port??

```
int main()
{
    struct mframe {
        unsigned short address;
        unsigned short func_code;
        unsigned short byte_count;
        unsigned int startaddress;
        unsigned short crc;
    };
    string ConfigPath = "myname.csv";
    // char getaddress(char addr);
    // bool setaddress(char addr);
    mframe frame[1000];
    int point_count = 0;
    vector<vector<string> > matrix;
    string line;
    ifstream file(ConfigPath);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        perror("error while opening file");
    }
    getline(file, line, '\n'); // deletes first row of column headers
    while (getline(file, line, '\n')) // find the endline charcater
    {
        vector<string> vec;
        string linevec;
        istringstream ss(line); // allows for parsing each line

        while (getline(ss, linevec, ',')) {
            vec.push_back(
                linevec); // push the parsed data for that line into a vector
        }

        matrix.emplace_back(vec); // push each parsed line into another vector
        frame[point_count].address = stoi(vec[0]);
        frame[point_count].func_code = stoi(vec[1]);
        frame[point_count].byte_count = stoi(vec[2]);
        frame[point_count].startaddress = stoi(vec[3]);
        frame[point_count].crc = stoi(vec[4]);
        point_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of qtcreator in your development does not imply that you use the Qt framework, besides that it does not influence what you want to do.

Comment: I cant construct a packet***.

Comment: using the Modbus container class sees like the way to go as it have all the tools for requesting a packet.

Comment: If you want a `packet ***` your design has already gone off the rails. I recommend stopping and rethinking to get the indirection down to something reasonable.

Comment: I don't get how I'm doing this wrong, this how we will create the packet based on what's in the CSV file it my choice. With that said I get a line and parse it and assign it to its variable so not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Not my choice **

Comment: Hello can someone help????